# Judicial Crimes

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, judiciary

Who implements Article III, Section 1 in the U.S. Constitution wherein "The judges, both of the supreme and inferior courts, shall hold their offices during good behavior..."?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean who decides what is good behavior, congress does. Congress would impeach a judge if he/she needed to be removed.

> With respect to federal judges, under Article I of the United States Constitution, the House of Representatives has the power to impeach, and the Senate the power to hold a trial to determine whether removal is appropriate. The House can impeach a judge with a simple majority vote. However, a judge may only be removed from office following a trial and a vote to convict by a two-thirds majority of the Senate.
>   https://www.brennancenter.org/blog/impeachment-and-removal-judges-explainer